# selecting value from drop down dropdown

Tags: php, html

hello please me out while editing the drop down box value how we show the value from the previous database Like v do over here

```
`<input name="starttime" size="8" value="<?php echo $res['starttime'];?>" /`>
```

so how can i do same for this code

```
<select name="employee_id" id="employee_id" >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <?php 

$task = new Task();
$task->connect();
echo $emp = $task->getEmployee();
$task->disconnect();
?>
</select>


function getEmployee()
{
$this->query=("select * from employee");
$rd=$this->executeQuery();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rd))
{

$pno = $row['pno'];
$name = $row['name'];

echo   "<option value='$pno'>$name</option>";
}
}

}
```

if i put over here in the value value then it will take one its value but it will no show in the drop down box . so in short it pick value from the array and show in dropdown box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select your wanted value on your dropdown list.

```
echo "<option value='$pno'" . ($pno == $selectedValue ? " selected='selected'" : "") . ">$name</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks but it always selets the first value we have not from the database value

Comment: Of course. You _do_ have to define `$selectedValue` for it to know what value to select. Since you haven't shown how you get the 'pno' of the employee you want I can't give you that part.